# Potential memory risks from linking a statically built library to a shared library using Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker, boost-asio, firebreath

I'm working on a cross-platform Firebreath plugin which is crashing on Windows. I use a static library containing classes which reference boost.asio. When I link this library against the plugin dll, I observe crashes when interacting with the io_service subsystem (ie, during socket construction). When I link the static library against an ordinary executable, the problem does *not* occur. When I compile the contents of the static library directly into the plugin dll project, the crash does *not* occur. I have gone to great lengths to ensure that all aspects of my build environment on Windows are consistent (build modes, version of Visual Studio, etc). In addition, I've firewalled the boost.asio headers, so that the plugin dll code has no visibility of the boost.asio sub-system (to no effect, unfortunately, vs2008 and vs2010). As far as I can tell, I've done everything possible to ensure that the build environment is well behaved but the problem persists.

Can the community offer any advice on potential risks or approaches which could expose or solve the problem?

Comment: can you post a [short, self contained, correct example](http://sscce.org) describing the problem?

Comment: Clearly there's a compiler options mismatch between your DLL project and the static library project.  Iterator debugging is a particularly nasty one, it changes the layout of the standard C++ class objects.  VS2010 contains a linker option that protect against that.  There are others, default packing, CRT version, overriding the new operator, etcetera.  Carefully compare the settings.

Comment: @Hans, I've already closely examined the compiler options for the dll and static lib, no difference apart from debug file output, etc.

Comment: @SamMiller, I'll try and see if it can isolate the problem.

Comment: Well, nothing to look at to diagnose this problem.  Post the project files on a file sharing service if you want another set of eyes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things that are dramatically different between linking a static library vs loading a DLL:

- global initialization: In a DLL, they all run.  In a static library, the linker only brings in an object file if it satisfies some unresolved external, so systems which rely on components registering themselves using the constructor or intiialization expression of a global object fail.
- shared CRT: In a static library, all calls to the Standard library are resolved during link time, and the main application and library function all call the same copy of the Standard library.  In a DLL, you risk having two copies of the Standard library, which can be ok if you're careful never to share any Standard library objects (like `FILE*`, `std::string`, or even `malloc`/`free` pairs) between library and application.

The second thing is most likely what's biting you.  There's a lazy way to fix it: Use the Standard library DLL, and a better way of fixing it: figure out memory and object lifetime and don't try to allocate on one side and free on the other, or share C++ class layout across the boundary.  Virtual functions work fine across the boundary.

The advantage of the "better" way is that plugins can be built in any version of the compiler, which becomes a big deal for maintenance later on in the development cycle.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, both the DLL and static lib are compiled against the Static Multithreaded runtimes (/Mt and /MtD). I'm starting to suspect that global initialization is the problem, there's several static globals nested deep in the boost.asio library, I'll attempt a 'short, self contained, correct example' to test this theory.

Comment: @GearoidMurphy: Using the static runtime is exactly what will break if you're allocating inside the library and freeing in the application, or vice versa.  Trying to share any runtime objects will fail, whether it be the heap, `FILE*`s, `std::string` or `std` namespace containers, etc.

Comment: But if they're compiled against the same runtime, won't they use the same heap?

Comment: Really!???, everything I've read suggests that compiling against a consistent runtime configuration will result in a consistent heap, can you provide some documentation that clarifies this?, I can't offhand recall if any free/delete operations cross the static/dll boundary, I'll check tomorrow...

Comment: @GearoidMurphy: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/09/15/755966.aspx  "If you choose to link with the static runtime library, then your module has its own private copy of the C/C++ runtime. When your module calls new or malloc, the memory can only be freed by your module calling delete or free. If another module calls delete or free, that will use the C/C++ runtime of that other module which is not the same as yours."

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8256/discussion-between-gearoid-murphy-and-ben-voigt)

Comment: Just to note: the problem was global initialisation, the hacky fix was to declare an instance of boost::asio::io_service and boost::asio::ip::resolver in the dll, this forced the initialisation of the boost::asio static globals. The problem is likely related to a linker config, will update when I know more.

Answer (score 0):

In the FireBreath plugin prep script, try [turning on the WITH_DYNAMIC_MSVC_RUNTIME flag](http://www.firebreath.org/display/documentation/Prep+Scripts#PrepScripts-Windowsparams).